# ng-include rendering before src is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to find a way that the directive `ng-include` is not trying to render before a value on scope is set. Is that possible?

Here is the example:

```
<ng-include src="'./lib/templates/' + $parent.currentEditable.editTemplate"></ng-include>
```

I think angular is trying to render that before `$parent.currentEditable.editTemplate` is defined. In the console I get:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/admin/lib/templates/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-if to hold off rendering til src is set

```
<ng-include ng-if="$parent.currentEditable.editTemplate" src="'./lib/templates/' + $parent.currentEditable.editTemplate"></ng-include>
```

Answer (score 0):

And use ng-src instead of src.

This way angular will wait for all expressions to evaluate and then create valid src